# adding set of columns in row in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

i am a newbie in cassandra. I am not sure about adding set of columns in a row many times, e.g., i want to add call related information columns (columns like timestamp_calling_no, timestamp_tower_id, timestamp_start_time, timestamp_end_time, timestamp_duration, timestamp_call_type,etc.) in a row whenever same mobile number make a call by using hector/astyanax/java/CQL.

please give your suggestions. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding columns to a row is an inexpensive operation and one more thing cassandra stores column names as sorted, so by using timestamp as a column name will solve the problem of slicing.cassandra can have 2 billion columns in a row in the CDR CF, so we can easily keep adding columns. 
you were trying to run a query which required cassandra to scan all rows then yes, it would perform poorly.

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you recognise that there are a number of APIs available. I would recommend using `CQL3`, mostly because thrift apis are now being kept only for backwards compatibility and because `CQL` can be used with most languages while `Astyanax` and `hector` are java specific.

I'd use a [compound key](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1) (under "Clustering, compound keys, and more").

```
//An example keyspace using CQL2
cqlsh>
 CREATE KEYSPACE calls WITH strategy_class = 'SimpleStrategy'
 AND strategy_options:replication_factor = 1;

//And next create a CQL3 table with a compound key
//Compound key is formed from the number and call's start time
cqlsh>
 CREATE TABLE calls.calldata (
      number text,
      timestamp_start_time timestamp,
      timestamp_end_time timestamp,
      PRIMARY KEY (number, timestamp_start_time)
    ) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
```

The above schema would allow you to insert a row containing the same number as a key multiple times but because the start of the call is part of the key, it will ensure that the combination creates a unique key each time.

Next insert some test data using CQL3(for the purpose of the example of-course)

```
cqlsh>  //This example data below uses 2 diffrent numbers
 insert into calls.calldata (number, timestamp_start_time, timestamp_end_time)
 values ('+441234567890', 1335361733545850, 1335361773545850);
 insert into calls.calldata (number, timestamp_start_time, timestamp_end_time)
 values ('+440987654321', 1335361734678700, 1335361737678700);
 insert into calls.calldata (number, timestamp_start_time, timestamp_end_time)
 values ('+441234567890', 1335361738208700, 1335361738900032);
 insert into calls.calldata (number, timestamp_start_time, timestamp_end_time)
 values ('+441234567890', 1335361740100277, 1335361740131251);
 insert into calls.calldata (number, timestamp_start_time, timestamp_end_time)
 values ('+440987654321', 1335361740176666, 1335361740213000);
```

And now we can retreive all the data (again using CQL3):

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM calls.calldata;

 number        | timestamp_start_time      | timestamp_end_time
---------------+---------------------------+---------------------------
 +440987654321 | 44285-12-05 15:11:18+0000 | 44285-12-05 16:01:18+0000
 +440987654321 | 44285-12-05 16:42:56+0000 | 44285-12-05 16:43:33+0000
 +441234567890 | 44285-12-05 14:52:25+0000 | 44285-12-06 01:59:05+0000
 +441234567890 | 44285-12-05 16:10:08+0000 | 44285-12-05 16:21:40+0000
 +441234567890 | 44285-12-05 16:41:40+0000 | 44285-12-05 16:42:11+0000
```

Or part of of the data. Because a compound key is used you can retrieve all the rows of a specific number using CQL3:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM calls.calldata WHERE number='+441234567890';     

 number        | timestamp_start_time      | timestamp_end_time
---------------+---------------------------+---------------------------
 +441234567890 | 44285-12-05 14:52:25+0000 | 44285-12-06 01:59:05+0000
 +441234567890 | 44285-12-05 16:10:08+0000 | 44285-12-05 16:21:40+0000
 +441234567890 | 44285-12-05 16:41:40+0000 | 44285-12-05 16:42:11+0000
```

And if you want to be really specific, you can retrieve a specific number where the call started at a specific time (again thanks to the compound key)

```
    cqlsh> SELECT * FROM calls.calldata WHERE number='+441234567890' 
           and timestamp_start_time=1335361733545850;

 number        | timestamp_start_time      | timestamp_end_time
---------------+---------------------------+---------------------------
 +441234567890 | 44285-12-05 14:52:25+0000 | 44285-12-06 01:59:05+0000
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail solution, but i want to store all call data made by same person in a single row, coz Cassandra is a horizontal efficient database. we should prefer adding column instead of adding row. The main challenge in my solution is slicing of column.

Answer (score 1):

In frameworks like Playorm, there are multiple ways to do that. For e.g. you can use @OneToMany OR @NoSqlEmbedded pattern. For more details, visit http://buffalosw.com/wiki/Patterns-Page/